# How can I implement functions outlined in a C header file using kotlin/native?

Tags: kotlin-native

I'm trying to write a libretro core using Kotlin/native.  A libretro core consists of a C library (dynamic or static) which exports all the functions outline in [libretro.h](https://github.com/libretro/libretro-common/blob/master/include/libretro.h).  I believe this should be possible because kotlin/native is capable of exporting a library which can be called by a C program, but I've not yet managed to get it to output a library which even resembles the libretro header file.

My initial approach involved building a klib file using the cinterop tool and hoping that it would allow me to make a class implement the header as an interface.  This didn't work and I've since moved towards trying to make my kotlin code output a C Header file which resembles the libretro header file.   I've not had any luck with either of these methods and I haven't been able to think of another way using purely kotlin/native.

My code

```
val RETRO_DEVICE_NONE: Int = 0

@CName(externName = "hello", shortName = "hello")
fun hello(): String = "Hello, Kotlin/Native!"

@CName(externName = "helloInt", shortName = "helloInt")
fun helloInt(): Int = 123

fun main(args: Array<String>) {
    println(hello())
}
```

ends up looking like [this](https://pastebin.com/mXJ2zWe5) once it has been exported to a header.  I can use the @CName annotation to lift a function out of the package structs it is placed in by default, but I still run into issues with function type signatures, #define macros, and enums (and probably other things, but those are the ones i've ran into so far).